# Does the blood removed from the body still have immunity?

Tags: virus, immune-system, blood, antibodies, white-blood-count

I know that blood contains white blood cells (which attack pathogens). Suppose we take half a liter of blood out of the body and implant the virus into it. Can the white blood cells in that half a liter of blood attack the virus and make antibodies?

Comment: Creation of antibodies is a somewhat complex process that involves various cells and tissues, not just a bucket of blood, see here for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibody

Comment: I think the question is ambiguous: Blood (more specifically: the blood serum) which contains antibodies ["**has** immunity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serum_(blood)#Clinical_and_laboratory_uses) (the question title). Whether blood without the remaining organism can produce antibodies and hence **obtain** immunity is a different question to which the answer is probably "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual approach is to use a whole animal such as horses

> The results of our research indicate that healthy horses
>   immunized with the SARS-CoV F69 strain can be induced to
>   generate effective, specific and neutralizing antibodies

and to prevent anaphylaxis

> Heterogenous antisera used for treatment possibly
>   result in anaphylactoid severe acute side-effects[28]. To avoid
>   the side-effects caused by horse antiserum, IgG against
>   SARS-CoV was digested with pepsin and purified with anion-exchange separations to exclude the immunogenicity of
>   Fc fragments and to retain the special activity of binding the
>   antigen of F(ab')2 fraction. The titers of neutralizing F(ab')2
>   against SARS-CoV was detected at higher level (1:5120). And
>   approximately 15 g F(ab')2 fragments were obtained from 1 litre antiserum, with the purity above 90%.

https://www.nature.com/articles/aps2005215.pdf